# 'setIsRelativeAnchorPoint:' is deprecated

Tags: math, cocos2d-iphone, deprecated

in the CCLayerColor.m

if ((self = [super init]))

```
{


    [self setIsRelativeAnchorPoint:YES];
    self.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5,0.5);
```

}

But prompt method has deprecated.Who knows how to find not deprecated method?

Comment: look at cocos2d.h and tell me you cocos2d version

Comment: I think the new equivalent is ignoreAnchorPointForPosition

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// v1.0
node.isRelativeAnchorPoint = YES;

// v2.0
node.ignoreAnchorPointForPosition = NO;  // The value is "negated"
```